# apt-get doesn't register newly added repository

Tags: debian, apt-get

I have added a new repository to the /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://mirrors.nic.cz/R/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
```

But when I install new packages (r-base), they are not taken from there! And when I look if this repository is being taken into account (using [a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679679/684229)), it doesn't appear to be:

```
root@apkserver2:~# apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://hwraid.le-vert.net/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
     release o=hwraid.le-vert.net,a=wheezy,l=hwraid.le-vert.net,c=main
     origin hwraid.le-vert.net
 500 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=wheezy-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.cz.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
     release v=7.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.cz.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

How to solve this issue? Does anything have to be run or restarted after I change the sources.list?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but have you updated the package listings? `apt-get update`. You may also need to clear the package cache (`apt-get clean`).

Comment: No I haven't! I am apt-get newbie!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a new repository in Debian, you also need to update the package listings. Run `apt-get update` as root to grab the new listings. You may also need to clear the package cache, so run `apt-get clean` (also as root).

Comment: And also I noticed that perhaps the order of items in `sources.list` matters? Seems that if you add at the end it has priority over what is before it.